# Email library not sending the correct link

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following code:

```
$link = "www.domain.com/profile/forgot_password?user=".$username . "&key=".$key;
$this->email->message('You requested to reset your password. Follow the link. <a href="'.$link.'"> ' . $link . "</a>.    Thank you,System Support.");
```

All I am trying to here is create a friendly message to the user when they wish to reset their password. It is supposed to be:

> You requested to reset your password. Click here to do so!

On the click here word it should have link in href to go to reset page. This is not working as the above code seems to be escaping html so it is showing the below in the message sent. It should interpret HTML tags not send them.

```
<a href='hdkjahskjdaskhdsjkahd'> djadjalksjdklasjdkajsd</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have set the appropriate email preferences to send an email in HTML format, particularly the `mailtype` preference:

```
//You can add more email preferences here too
$config['mailtype'] = html;
$this->email->initialize($config);

$link = "www.domain.com/profile/forgot_password?user=".$username . "&key=".$key;
$this->email->message('You requested to reset your password. Follow the link. <a href="'.$link.'"> ' . $link . "</a>.    Thank you,System Support.");
```

If you prefer, you can store your email preferences in a config file:

> Simply create a new file called the `email.php`, add the `$config` array
>   in that file. Then save the file at `config/email.php` and it will be
>   used automatically.

---

CodeIgniter's user guide also [specifies that](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html):

> If you send HTML email you must send it as a complete web page.

So, that means including all of the relevant tags that you would use to create a webpage (`<html>`, `<body>` etc.). In order to make this easier to manage, you can store the email template in a *view* file, for example:

```
application/views/email_templates/password_reset.php
```

This file can include the relevant HTML to send as an email, for example:

```
//Other appropriate HTML tags...    
<p>You requested to reset your password. Follow the link. <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a>. Thank you, System Support.</p>
//Other appropriate HTML tags...
```

You can then pass the *link* to the view, and send the view as an email:

```
$data['link'] = "www.domain.com/profile/forgot_password?user=".$username . "&key=".$key;
$email_message = $this->load->view('email_templates/password_reset', $data, true);
$this->email->message($email_message);
```

(I haven't included all of the required email functions like `to()`, `send()` etc. but these should be easy enough to work out.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Set  **mailtype** to **html**